# How to fix this red underline when using Flow in WebStorm in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm, flowtype

I tried to describe the problem with screenshots. In addition, JSHint here doesn't seem to play any role. There is an ESLint config has been set up, so all the code is edited according to ESLint. But anyway I don't know how this underline can be fixed.

*One more note:*

I also went to **Settings > Languages and Frameworks > JavaScript**.
There is **JavaScript language version** is set up to **Flow**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the screenshots it's clear that the error comes from JSHint. This linter is quite old and is not designed to work with Flow syntax. Did you try turning it off in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshots it's clear that the error comes from JSHint. This linter is quite old and is not designed to work with Flow syntax. Please try turning it off in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint**